# Estimating the Intraclass Correlation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, anova

Chapter 2 of [Multilevel Modeling Using R](https://www.mlminr.com/) introduces the intraclass correlation (in the context of a model with one cluster variable treated as a random effect) as $$\rho_{I} = \frac{\tau^2}{\sigma^2 + \tau^2}$$

where $\tau^2$ is the population variance between clusters, and $\sigma^2$ is the population variance of within cluster.

The empirical estimator of $\sigma^2$ is given as $$\frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{C}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_j}\big(y_{ij} - \bar{y}_j\big)^2}{N-C}$$

where $C$ is the number of clusters, $N$ is the total number of observations, $y_{ij}$ is the $i^{th}$ observation in the $j^{th}$ cluster, and $\bar{y}_j$ is the mean outcome in the $j^{th}$ cluster.

I recognize this formula as the formula for the "Mean Square Error" from a one-way ANOVA.

The empirical estimator of $\tau^2$ is given as $$\frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{C}n_j\big(\bar{y}_j - \bar{y}\big)^2}{\tilde{n}(C-1)} - \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\tilde{n}}$$

where $C$ is the number of clusters, $n_j$ is the total number of observations in cluster $C$, $\bar{y}_j$ is the mean outcome in the $j^{th}$ cluster, and $\bar{y}$ is the grand mean.

I recognize the first term in this formula as the "Mean Square Treatment" from a one-way ANOVA, with one complication I don't understand: the $\tilde{n}$.

$\tilde{n}$ is described as the "adjusted mean cluster size" and defined as $$\frac{1}{C-1}\bigg[N - \frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{C}n_j^2}{N} \bigg]$$.

But, no other discussion of $\tilde{n}$ is given. I am curious about two questions:

1. **Why is the "adjusted mean cluster size" calculated in such a way?**
2. **Why is the "adjusted mean cluster size" included in the denominator of the "Mean Square Treatment", which would normally just divide by $C-1$?**